# Read and write to an XML file in UnityScript

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I just started Unity and have used JavaScript for a while.  I want to read and write on this XML file I made.  For example, every time I earn any money or xp on the game, I want to update this file and add the money and xp earned.  This example below is my main data xml file.

**Before the player earns money**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<levels>
    <lvl1><unlocked>TRUE</unlocked></lvl1>
</levels>
<money>1000</money>
<xp>1000</xp>
```

**After the player earns $267 and 2000xp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<levels>
    <lvl1><unlocked>TRUE</unlocked></lvl1>
</levels>
<money>1267</money>
<xp>3000</xp>
```

I also want to fetch the money and xp so that on the HUD, the players can see how much money they have and how much xp they have.  Please feel free to ask me for any other resources you may need.  I have already declared two integers: money and xp.  I have not found this in the [Unity API manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/index.html) or Mozilla Developer Network

```
var money = 0 //default variable for money
var xp = 0 //default variable for xp
```